# Random Article Button

Tags: 7

I'd like to create a button on a menu bar that can generate a link to a random article from my blog posts (much like Wikipedia has). It's for a client, and they'd like to have this functionality on the site.

I had a theoretical solution: have a .txt or .xml file containing a list of all the URLs to each of the posts, with a "key" assigned to each of them. Then, when the user clicks the random article button, the current time (ex. 1:45) is hashed and mapped to a specific URL. I am fairly new to Drupal, however, I was wondering if there was some way to have the random article button use a .c file to execute these steps. The site is being hosted on a server that uses Apache 2, and I looked through some modules that were implemented in C code. I'm pretty new to all of this, and spent many fruitless hours searching for solutions. It would be great if someone could provide a link to an article that explains how to execute c files on apache or a better alternative method to achieve my goal!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a very broad question; then this site is about Drupal, so we cannot teach you anything about C code to use on server side. Drupal is written in PHP; C is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the module [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) can do that:

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
>       You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
>       You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
>       You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you like.
>       You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
>       You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
>       You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>   "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>   displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for
>   that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.

set it up as a page of content with whatever settings you want. If you're not familiar with Views, look at the documentation and do a search - there are lots of tutorials out there.

To do what you want, you would Sort by Random, and set the Pager to a specific count of 1.